# Countdown timer - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for quizzes that students can take on a website. The time limit would be 2 hours but for some reason I can only get my code to decrement minutes, not hours. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    hours = 2;
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (diff <= 0) {
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
  };
  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(seconds, display);
};
```

```html
<div>Time remaining: <span id="time">2:00:00</span></div>
```

Comment: You're setting `hours` to `2` and never changing it. Shouldn't you be getting the hours from `diff` just like you are the minutes and seconds?

Comment: `startTimer(seconds, display)` is incorrect. `seconds` is undefined. `seconds` only exists in the timer function, so you should also set `seconds` as a global variable.

Comment: Also (this has nothing to do in answering your question) 1000 ms in JavaScript is kinda slow. I recommend using 950 ms for your countdown (don't worry, 50 ms is the time it takes to blink so it won't speed up too much)

Answer (score 4):

You are not currently calculating the hours. They are assigned a constant value i.e. `2`. Update the line `hours = 2;` with

```js
hours = (diff / 3600) | 0;
```

Currently, minutes can be greater than `60`. So, that line should be:

```js
minutes = (diff / 60) % 60 | 0;
```

Moreover, You have not declared the variable `seconds` when calling from `window.onload` event. It should be like:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let seconds = 2 * 60 * 60; // 2 hours to seconds
  var display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(seconds, display); // alternatively, you can pass value directly without declaring a variable.
};
```

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds;

  function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    hours = (diff / 3600) | 0;
    minutes = (diff / 60) % 60 | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (diff <= 0) {
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
  };
  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

//window.onload = function () {
var display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(2 * 60 * 60, display);
//};
```

```html
<div>Time remaining: <span id="time">2:00:00</span></div>
```

Comment: Please add a line explaining that `seconds` is not defined also

Comment: Sure, I will. I ignored that maybe the person has defined that somewhere else and not included that part.